# Out put from a function to an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, function

I'm trying to change the output from my function, which at the moment is a print output.
this is the function, which going through pairs of sequences from two text files, if the paired sequence matches length, then it counts the differences, if the paired sequence is different length it returns "-1"
just not sure how I can out put this as an array.
thanks kindly

```
def diff_dna_nuc(seq1, seq2):   
    if  len(seq1) != len(seq2): #(if length of two sequences are different)
        print(-1)

    else:
        diff=sum(c1!=c2 for c1, c2 in zip(seq1,seq2)) #(if length of two sequences are the same, count the differences in the sequence)
        print(diff)

#and this calls the function

for x in range (0,80):
    diff_dna_nuc(dna1[x],dna2[x])
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what exactly you're looking for. Obviously you need to replace the `print()` calls with `return` statements, then assign the results to a variable instead of just calling the function like you're currently doing. What else (if anything) are you trying to do?

Comment: Functions like that shouldn't print ANYTHING (except for debugging).  They should RETURN their result, and allow the caller to decide what to do with that result.